# Byte Array to a Signed Integer in VB6

Tags: vb6, arrays

I am having trouble converting from a Byte Array to a Signed Integer in VB6. This would be simple to do with BitConverter in .NET but I'm not sure what to do with VB6.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no built in function, you need to write one. Here is a quick sample to get you started.

```
Private Function BArrayToInt(ByRef bArray() As Byte) As Integer
    Dim iReturn As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(bArray) - LBound(bArray)
        iReturn = iReturn + bArray(i) * 2 ^ i
    Next i

    BArrayToInt = iReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Note that this only converts a single 4 byte array into a single `Long` value.

Answer (score 1):

[CopyMemory](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18519)

Air code (may crash your PC, cause dinosaur attack, etc).

```
Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dest As Any, _ source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)  

Dim a() As Byte 
Dim n As Integer 
 'get the bytes somehow into a()
CopyMemory n, a(0), 2
```