# Converting 2 bytes to an integer in VB 6

Tags: vb6

I need to convert 2 bytes to an integer in VB6

I currently have the byte array as:

```
bytArray(0) = 26
bytArray(1) = 85
```

the resulting number I assume should be 21786

I need these 2 turned into an integer so I can convert to a single and do additional arithmetic on it.

How do I get the integer of the 2 bytes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte Array to a Signed Integer in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314896/byte-array-to-a-signed-integer-in-vb6)

Answer (score 2):

If your assumed value is correct, the pair of array elements are stored in little endian format.  So the following would convert the two array elements into a signed short integer.

```
Dim Sum As Integer
Sum = bytArray(0) + bytArray(1) * 256
```

Note that if your elements would sum to more than 32,767 (bytArray(1) >= 128), you'll see an overflow exception occur.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert to an integer first, you can go directly to a single, using the logic shown by @MarkL

```
 Dim Sngl as Single
 Sngl = (bytArray(1) * 256!) + bytArray(0)
```

Edit: As @BillHileman notes, this will give an unsigned result. Do as he suggests to make it signed.

Comment: That's fine as long as the result is < 32767, otherwise it should subtract 32767 and reverse the sign.